# How to show popup in random time and random message dialog?

Tags: javascript, popup, dialog

How would I showing popup using javascript or jquery in random time and random message ?
Exemple : after 5 second, popup will showing message "Hallo World 1" than after 18 second, popup will showing message "Hallo World 2" and after 23 second popup will showing message "Hallo World 3", etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.random()` and `setTimeout`.

Would be something like this:

```
function startRandomizer(){

  window.setTimeout( function(){

    window.alert("Hello World " + Math.random() * 1000);
    startRandomizer();

  }, Math.random() * 100 + 10); // From 10 to 110 secconds

} 

startRandomizer(); // Call it once, and it will do it forever...
```

Note that, `Math.random()` returns a floating number between 0 and 1. If you multiply it by 100, it will be between 0 and 100.  If you want it to be between 50 and 100 (for example), multiply by 50 and sum 50... You got the idea.

Comment: You forgot to add iterations for each call. Make the `setTimeout` increment a variable in the `startRandomizer` parent scope and output that instead.

Comment: Yeah, but then it wouldn't be a "random message" too @Makaze

Comment: I guess the question is ambiguous. It implies he wants iterations and randomness, depending on which part you read.

Comment: Yeah... you are correct. I suppose the random example he used, coincidently was "1" "2" and "3"... haha

Comment: thanks for your answer @Ivan. yeah what I mean is show message as random like "Hello world" than "loremipsum" and "dolorsitamet" etc..